# How to get performance stats of the invoked AWS lambda task?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am submitting tasks (eventually this will be hundreds of thousands of tasks) to AWS lambda using [`InvokeRequest` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.html), and I am interested in performance characteristics of the task: execution time, memory usage, etc.

Note that I will eventually want to compute various performance statistics and plots of the submitted tasks in costum code.

Answer (score 3):

You can get execution time (Duration), Error count, Invocation count and Throttles metrics in CloudWatch. For memory usage I think you would have to pull that from CloudWatch Logs somehow. You might start by looking at [this AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=705976) which discusses AWS Lambda memory profiling.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.